# Recording External Application to Eclipse from Q7 capture and record tool

Tags: eclipse-rcp, ui-testing, testautomationfx

I working with an eclipse based mobile app development IDE which triggers Android emulators to run the apps. I like to automate the testing procedure of this IDE using Xored Q7 automation tool, but I don't find any way to record the test after triggering the emulator. Could you please tell me whether Q7 have such feature?
I mean, I can verify the test success if and only if the app works fine in emulator or the actual device. So, It needs to be recorded the behavior of app in the emulator or mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q7 doesn't provide any features to record an application outside the Eclipse IDE. We can use some scripts to do those stuffs. Sikuli scripting or shell scripting can do those for some extent.